# Looping a Function like Wordpress have_posts

Tags: php, wordpress, function, while-loop

I am trying to loop a function through while similar to WordPress. I use the function to return a boolean of true or false. Now here is my function. Now, with it only returning true or false, I know that I have to get my function `has_rows();` to change to false after it looks through all my rows. Is this possible?

So I guess my question is if it is possible, and how, to loop the a function in a while loop like the below example. I know it is possible because wordpress uses a function, my question is how.

THIS is what I have tried. And the loop wont stop.

```
function has_rows () {
    global $Q_INFO;
    global $DB_CONN;

    static $COUNT; // STATIC TO REMEMBER LAST TIME FUNCTION CALLED
    $COUNT = @$COUNT ? $COUNT++ : 0; // IF NOT SET, SET TO 0 AND COUNT EACH LOOP

    echo $QUERY = "SELECT * FROM `" . $Q_INFO['table'] . "` LIMIT " . $COUNT . ", 1";

    $STMT = $DB_CONN->prepare($QUERY);
    $STMT->execute();

    $RESULT = $STMT->get_result();

    $STMT->close();

    if ($RESULT->num_rows > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Im calling it just like in wordpress:

```
<?php if (has_rows()):?>
    <?php while (has_rows()): ?>
        Hi World!!
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

HERE IS MY FINAL CODE:
I had to add another static variable for the very first call of the function in `if(has_rows()):` and then I used the selected answer below to do the rest.

Thanks for the help guys!

```
function has_rows () {
global $Q_INFO;
global $DB_CONN;

static $I = 0;
static $COUNT = 0;

if ($I == 0) {
    $QUERY = "SELECT * FROM `" . $Q_INFO['table'] . "`";
    $I++;
} else {
    $QUERY = "SELECT * FROM `" . $Q_INFO['table'] . "` LIMIT " . $COUNT . ", 1";
    $COUNT++;
}

$STMT = $DB_CONN->prepare($QUERY);
$STMT->execute();

$RESULT = $STMT->get_result();

$STMT->close();

if ($I != 0) {
    while ($ROW = $RESULT->fetch_assoc()) {
        foreach ($ROW as $KEY=>$VALUE) {
            $Q_INFO[$KEY] = $VALUE;
        }
    }
}

if ($RESULT->num_rows > 0) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you run it, `$COUNT` is `0`, which evaluates to boolean `false`. So, `$COUNT = @$COUNT ? $COUNT++ : 0;` sets it to `0` again.

Just take out that line, explicitly initialize `$COUNT` to `0`, and put `$COUNT++;` right before your final `if` statement.

```
function has_rows () {
    global $Q_INFO;
    global $DB_CONN;

    static $COUNT = 0; // STATIC TO REMEMBER LAST TIME FUNCTION CALLED
    // Other code here...
    $COUNT++;
    if ($RESULT->num_rows > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, but it only solved the second part of my riddle, on first call `if(has_rows())` is the first call, so if I call the function, then count becomes 1 more than the first row, so I had to add a second variable $I into the equation and then use your answer within.

Answer (score 1):

If your trying just to walk over an array, like the wordpress does, try this:

```
$posts = array('post1', 'post2', 'post3');

function has_posts()
{
    // this line will make sure that you have a non empty array
    if ( ! is_array($posts) or ! count($posts)) return false;
    else return each($posts);
}

while ($post = has_posts())
{
    echo $post;
}
```

Comment: Outputting an array would not work to determine simply `if(have_posts())` I would have to do `if (count(have_posts()) > 0)` and that is twice as much to write, and over lots of php pages, it is a big time save. But thanks for the idea :)

Comment: And you said like wordpress, this is not how wordpress does it.

Comment: You can't use the same function as your iterator AND as a check, to make sure that the array is not empty.

Comment: If you look at my final code above, exactly what I said in the comment, and using the other answer by Ed, the code works fine. And in wordpress, their function works as a boolean only, so how else can explain exactly what they are doing? This is pretty close for me.